# MySQL - Increment Column Value or Insert Data if not Exists

Tags: mysql

I have users visiting the site.  The user can do a bunch of different actions.  I'd like a counter to count the amount of times the user does that action.  The problem is, it's per day, it starts over each day.
So the model has, **Id, User, Action, Times, Date**

I'd like to use this, but I can't because **Action** is not a key, and cannot be.  None of the  other fields can be a key either.

```
insert into useractions (user, action, times) values (2, 3, 1)
on duplicate key update times = times + 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you absolutely want to calculate the counter value at the time of inserting the action?  It may be simpler to simply keep track of the users and actions with timestamps, like so:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+
| UserID | ActionID | Time                |
+--------+----------+---------------------+
|      1 |        1 | 2012-01-19 14:47:03 |
|      1 |        2 | 2012-01-19 14:48:12 |
|      1 |        3 | 2012-01-19 14:48:15 |
|      2 |        1 | 2012-01-19 14:49:33 |
|      2 |        1 | 2012-01-18 14:49:42 |
```

And then calculate the daily tallies with a query:

```
SELECT UserID,
       ActionID,
       DATE(Time) AS Date,
       COUNT(*) AS n
FROM actions
GROUP BY UserID,ActionID,Date
ORDER BY Date,UserID,ActionID;

+--------+----------+------------+---+
| UserID | ActionID | Date       | n |
+--------+----------+------------+---+
|      1 |        2 | 2012-01-17 | 2 |
|      1 |        3 | 2012-01-17 | 2 |
|      3 |        2 | 2012-01-17 | 6 |
|      1 |        1 | 2012-01-18 | 1 |
|      1 |        2 | 2012-01-18 | 1 |
|      1 |        3 | 2012-01-18 | 4 |
```

Comment: ya i just think the user might visit 20 pages... and then ill have 20 pages per user, can get kinda big

Answer (score 8):

You left the data column out of your insert example, but you mentioned it several times so I'll assume that exists. Also, I'm assuming it's an actual date (not a timestamp or datetime).

If you add a unique index on (user,action,date) then your query will work.

Here's the DDL:

```
alter table useractions
  add unique index unique_idx (user,action,date);
```

And your DML (adding the date column):

```
insert into useractions (user, action, times, date) values (2, 3, 1, current_date())
on duplicate key update times = times + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique key on a combination of columns. That way you can make that combination (user, action, date) unique and your query should then work.

That really is the easiest solution. You do need rights to alter the table though.