# Discord.js XP system

Tags: mysql, sql, discord.js

I would like to make an xp system to my bot [Hello Bot](https://discordbots.org/bot/498514150306086922) with mysqli but my code does  work. not The mistake is that now I write the first time, stand it in the database, but someone else will have it twice in the database

[image]

my code:

```
   con.query(`SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  let sql;
  if (rows.length < 1) {
    sql = `INSERT INTO xp (id, xp) VALUES ('${message.author.id}', 30)`;
  }
  else {
    let xp = rows[0].xp;
    sql = 'UPDATE xp SET xp = ' + xp + 30;
  }
  con.query(sql);
});
```

Comment: "my code does not work" - why not? What happens? Do you get a specific error message? Is it just not updating the table, or the lambda not getting called, or something else?

Comment: Your update line is missing a WHERE clause. Is that the problem?

Comment: thanks I had not seen it but the mistake is there in now

Comment: That ID is the maximum value of a 32-bit int, so looks wrong to me. Is that really the ID? Shouldn't ID be the primary key of the table, so you wouldn't be allowed duplicates? If it is a key you can probably do [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8934471/243245) to add or increment a row instead, or you could run this whole thing in a transaction if there's a risk that you're running two copies of the code and they're both getting nothing from the select then both inserting a row, but I think there are other problems going on here too.

Comment: thanks it was the only mistake so had to do none more things will get i saw "xp" + 30 so if i had 30 already in 3030

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the Late Reply ,  I just saw this post and i have encountered this error before
What you should do is : Run `ALTER [TABLE_NAME] MODIFY [COLUMN_NAME] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;`   => Why this has to be done is because as your trying to store the author's id ,  it tries to but the discord member id has more digits than the range of INT type so if you do BIGINT the id can be stored in it and then you can continue with the program